# Quasiprimes in arithmetic progressions

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory

Let

$$\Lambda_z(n) = \sum_{d|n, d>z} \mu(d) \log(d/z).$$

As S. Graham proved in 1978,

$$\sum_{n\leq x} |\Lambda_z(n)|^2 \sim x \log(x/z).$$

provided $x\geq z$.

We also know that, by the large sieve or Brun-Titchmarsh,

$$\sum_{a mod q} \left|\mathop{\sum_{n\leq x}}_{n\equiv a \mod q} \Lambda(n)\right|^2$$

is at most about $2 x^2/q$.

Question: can one bound

$$\sum_{a mod q} \left|\mathop{\sum_{n\leq x}}_{n\equiv a \mod q} \Lambda_z(n)\right|^2$$

by at most about a constant times $x^2/q$?

(Of course one can bound it by $x^2 \log(x/z)/q$, by Graham's 1978 bound plus Cauchy-Schwarz. The better bound $x^2/q$ is easy for $q$ and $z$ small. I am interested in seeing a proof that works for $x/q\leq z\leq x$.)

Comment: Not exactly sure what your notation $z \equiv x$ means, but I think one can basically proceed by using the fact that $\Lambda_z$ concentrates on almost primes (e.g. Proposition 4.2 of the Polymath8b paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.4897 , there are also some works of Pintz in this direction).  In the Polymath8b paper we focused on the case of q the product of a number of small primes, but the arguments should extend.  We used a smoother cutoff than $\log(d/z) 1_{d>z}$, though this is perhaps not essential.

Comment: [Typo corrected.] I think the difference here is that you seem to be taking $z$ to be small (as in - about $x^\epsilon$), whereas I am thinking of $z$ as being large (as in - not much smaller than $x$). For $z$ small, I have no difficulty in expanding the last sum displayed above. (Indeed, in that case, one can estimate the inner sum well for any individual $a$.) I'd be very interested in seeing how to cope with $z$ in the range $x/q \leq z\leq x$.

Comment: I can think of an inelegant solution combining the large sieve with concentration on integers with no small factors. I could outline it below, but I'd prefer to see first whether other people can do better.

Comment: Proposition 4.2 of Polymath8b works even when $z$ is as large as $x^C$ for a fixed $C$ (it does not use any level of distribution results such as Bombieri-Vinogradov).  (Note that the support of $F_1,\dots,F_k$ in that proposition, while required to be compact, can be arbitrarily large.)  You may be thinking instead of Theorem 3.6, which provides an asymptotic for such sums (not just an upper bound) and does require smallness of $z$ in order to use a level of distribution result.

Comment: Aha, thanks. Well, my second comment still stands for now.